# Creating an array with objects from another class (Java)

Tags: java, arrays, class

I have created a class `Patientjournal` which contains a lot of information about various patients in a hospital, as well as methods for retrieving this information.

I have now created another class named `Section`.  In this class I wish to create an array of Patientjournal-objects.  I have tried to to this as follows:

```
private Patientjournal[] patientjournals;
```

However, this yields the error message

> "Patientjournal cannot be resolved to a type".

Why am I getting this message?  I don't understand this, because in the actual class `Patientjournal`, I have successfully been able to create an array with objects from yet *another* class using the same procedure, and this time without difficulties.

If anyone knows what may cause this I will greatly appreciate any help!

Answer (score 2):

We could use more information, but it sounds like a compiler issue.  Specifically, I'm assuming you don't have the necessary `import` statement; `import ext.site.Patientjournal` or whatever.

Comment: Gargh!  I just realized that I saved this class in the wrong folder!  My bad!  Thanks for the input :)